# Automated code review tool for cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I need automated code review or Testing tool for cakephp project ...When I search I am getting tools for only PHP code. Similar to [Tool For Php Code Analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156157/tool-for-php-code-analysis)

I know this is not the place to ask for suggestions. But I have searched and got no results. If no Automated tool what checklist suits for cakePHP[version 2.4] code review. Please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't those tools work for you? What are you specifically looking for?

Comment: When i add my code it says there are no errors or 0% error.But i know my code consists points to be changed as too many nested conditions,unused variables etc., its not possible to check using tools?

Comment: maybe try https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic "review" tool, you still need to use your brain and at least this set of tools. You can still write terrible code, even using these tools. They'll just check for things that can be automated checked. But there is no tool that will tell you "Hey this code is great!". These four tools are the minimum tools I would use to ensure the code is well written:

- [phpcs](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) with the [CakePHP coding standard](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer) (based on the silly PSR)
- [phpmd](https://phpmd.org/)
- [phpstan](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan)
- [phpunit](https://phpunit.de/)

For phpmd there is some experience required to interpret the results.

> When i add my code it says there are no errors or 0% error.But i know my code consists points to be changed as too many nested conditions,unused variables etc., its not possible to check using tools?

You need to write unit tests for your code for that and generate a code coverage report that shows you what is covered. But again, you can get a coverage green while still not having tested every possible path the code can take - be aware of that.

You can use a service like http://scrutinizer-ci.com/ as well that will do all the work for you and generate a report after each push. We're pretty happy with Scrutinizer but their custom analyser is even more picky than our configuration. Be prepared to get a ton of issues reported. ;)

Comment: @Webbie, you can find more details also here - http://mark-story.com/posts/view/static-analysis-tools-for-php.

Answer (score 0):

I use PHPStorm for writing code. It hints to many issues as unused variables, and many other things. There are other advanced code editors that hint for potential unsafe code.

Also, use unit testing, like phpunit. This latter allows also for advanced statistics, like code coverage and crap score, which is a measure of code complexity vs code coverage. It points to functions and methods that are too complex and need simplification or additional unit tests.

Comment: I use netbeans which hint some errors and warning .But it is already written code and difficult check when consists thousands of line.That's why looking for automation tool

Comment: How will you improve the code? Isn't it just by going through it and correct each error and warning? An automated tool could assess where are the most problems, but it would not correct it for you.